# Parsing an XML file in python for emailing purposes

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

I am writing code in python that can not only read a xml but also send the results of that parsing as an email. Now I am having trouble just trying to read the file I have in xml. I made a simple python script that I thought would at least read the file which I can then try to email within python but I am getting a Syntax Error  in line 4.

root.tag 'log'

Anyways here is the code I written so far:

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as etree

tree = etree.parse('C:/opidea.xml')
response = tree.getroot()
log = response.find('log').text
logentry = response.find('logentry').text
author = response.find('author').text
date = response.find('date').text
msg = [i.text for i in response.find('msg')]
```

Now the xml file has this type of formating

```
  <log>
<logentry
   revision="12345">
<author>glv</author>
<date>2012-08-09T13:16:24.488462Z</date>
<paths>
<path
   action="M"
  kind="file">/trunk/build.xml</path>
</paths>
 <msg>BUG_NUMBER:N/A
FEATURE_AFFECTED:N/A
   OVERVIEW:Example</msg>
</logentry>
</log>
```

I want to be able to send an email of this xml file. For now though I am just trying to get the python code to read the xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`response.find('log')` won't find anything, because:

> find(self, path, namespaces=None)
>
> Finds the first matching subelement, by tag name or path.

In your case `log` is not a subelement, but rather the root element itself. You can get its text directly, though: `response.text`. But in your example the `log` element doesn't have any text in it, anyway.

EDIT: Sorry, that quote from the docs actually applies to `lxml.etree` documentation, rather than `xml.etree`.

I'm not sure about the reason, but all other calls to `find` also return `None` (you can find it out by printing `response.find('date')` and so on). With [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) ou can use `xpath` instead:

```
author = response.xpath('//author')[0].text
msg = [i.text for i in response.xpath('//msg')]
```

In any case, your use of `find` is not correct for `msg`, because `find` always returns a single element, not a list of them.

Comment: Okay I removed the  

response.find('log')

What would the next step be? I am still getting that syntax error.

Comment: @Gilbert Please provide the full traceback when posting questions. I updated the answer with some more suggestions.