# Python script that can email in XML format

Tags: python, xml, xslt, lxml

Is it possible to create Python script that can email XML hierarchical format in the email Body by using XML documentation.

Just to give you the background, I am getting few details updated in XML document and wants to input the same XML format in email.

Currently, I have used XSL to style my XML document and Python "lxml" library to convert XML to HTML but my current script is removing the XML tags in final output.

So, I am looking for a way to retain these XML tags in my output, I preferably want to use the same method of XML to HTML because I need to load this HTML structure in my automated email.

**Python Script**

```py
from lxml import etree

xsl = etree.parse("tx.xsl")
updated = etree.XSLT(xsl)
xml = etree.parse("tx.xml")
html = updated(xml)

html.write("XML-Transformed.html")
```

---

**XSL Code**

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <table>
                    <xsl:for-each select="ROOT">
                           <tr>
                             <td><xsl:value-of select="Summary"/></td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                             <td><xsl:value-of select="customer_Name"/></td>
                           </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
     </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML**

```
<ROOT>
<Summary>ZZZZ</Summary>
<customer_Name>YYYY</customer_Name>
</ROOT>
```

**Current Output**

```html
ZZZZ
YYYY
```

**Expected**

```html
<Summary>ZZZZ</Summary>
<customer_Name>YYYY</customer_Name>
```

Comment: @mzjn Added, all details with my current code.

Comment: I agree with msjn. What are you trying to do? If you're just asking if it is possible, have you tried it yet? Do you know if it works or not? If it doesn't work, then we'll be able to help you more and give a better answer.

Comment: @12944qwerty Please see the post, I have updated the details. Is it not visible to you?

Comment: Oh. I had not seen it. Sorry.

Comment: @12944qwerty No problem, I have updated it very detailed manner.

Comment: If you could add current and expected output, it'd be useful.

Comment: Possible Duplicate found? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12059648/parsing-an-xml-file-in-python-for-emailing-purposes

Comment: @12944qwerty queries, might be similar but my requirement here is different, please go through my complete post.

Comment: @KonradBotor Sure, added.

Answer (score 1):

The way the XSLT transforms work, you need to explicilty add everything you want in the output to the transform. Also, if you want those XML tags displayed by the browser, they need to be [escaped](https://www.freeformatter.com/html-escape.html).

Try this XSLT file, open the result in a browser, and let me know if it's what you need:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <table>
                    <xsl:for-each select="ROOT">
                           <tr>
                             <td>&lt;Summary&gt;<xsl:value-of select="Summary"/>&lt;/Summary&gt;</td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                             <td>&lt;customer_Name&gt;<xsl:value-of select="customer_Name"/>&lt;/customer_Name&gt;</td>
                           </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
     </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

EDIT: If you want HTML with your custom tags, you need to explicitly add them to the XSLT transform - without escaping this time:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
     <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
            <body>
                <table>
                    <xsl:for-each select="ROOT">
                           <tr>
                             <td><Summary><xsl:value-of select="Summary"/></Summary></td>
                           </tr>
                           <tr>
                             <td><customer_Name><xsl:value-of select="customer_Name"/></customer_Name></td>
                           </tr>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
     </xsl:template>
 </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Konrad, I have already tried this way but it will not retain the original tags of XML in HTML and adding '&lt;' will escape < and > but this tags will merge up with text and the the HTML structure will look like <td>"<Summary>Text  Text</Summary>"</td>.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You need to escape those tags as they are not valid HTML tags. Unless of course in your actual XML those tags are valid HTML tags - in which case you simply need to copy-paster them to your XSLT file.

Comment: Thanks Konrad, I am exactly looking for a way so that I can create custom HTML Tags of "summary" and "customer_name" with the usual parsing of XML to HTML using Python script.
I had seen this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54992490/replacing-a-custom-html-tag-in-a-python-string) but wasn't able to apply it to my solution.